# How to convert string to ASCII decimal?

Tags: python, ascii

How can I convert an entire string into ASCII decimals? I know I can use `ord("a")` and `chr("97")`  to do a single character, but I need to convert an entire string, like `ord("Hello, World!")`. Maybe I can convert the individual characters of the string and append them to a variable, but that would be difficult and I'd like to avoid doing that. Is there a better way?

Comment: Please specify your problem clearly.  What, exactly, are "ASCII decimals"?  Give examples of sample input and output.  I suspect that you merely need to `apply` the `ord` function to each character of the string.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "convert an entire string". Do you want a list of `int` values? A single giant `int`, for example `"to"` would map  to something like `ord("t") << 32 | ord("o")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "Hello, World!"
nums = [ord(i) for i in string]
print(nums)
```

Prints:
`[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]`